# How to extract Metadata from File Geodatabase using Ogr2ogr?

Tags: file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, metadata

The Ogr2Ogr doc [says](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html#special-sql-requests):

> GetLayerDefinition a_layer_name” and “GetLayerMetadata a_layer_name” can be used as special SQL requests to get respectively the definition and metadata of a FileGDB table as XML content (only available in Geodatabases created with ArcGIS 10 or above)

I'm able to connect, since this works:

```
ogrinfo -so -q -nogeomtype /path/to/myfile.gdb
```

However when I try this:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect OpenFileGDB -sql "SELECT GetLayerMetadata(myfeatureclass)" /path/to/myfile.gdb
```

It says: `FAILURE: no source datasource provided`

With ArcGIS Pro, I can see the metadata for the featureclass.

Are there any examples for this somewhere?

Comment: Try `ogrinfo -sql "SELECT GetLayerMetadata myfeatureclass" /path/to/myfile.gdb`. Does that throw an error?

Comment: Thanks, but still fails.

Comment: And what is the message now?

Comment: Still get `FAILURE: no source datasource provided`

Comment: And you really used `ogrinfo` now? With ogr2ogr you read data from one place and write it out to another so both source and target are required.

Comment: Oops, yes, now with `ogrinfo -dialect OpenFileGDB -sql "SELECT GetLayerMetadata(myfeatureclass);" /path/to/myfile.gdb` I get: `Undefined function 'GetLayerMetadata' used`.  Without the parenthesis I get a parse error.

Comment: Sorry, we both need to concentrate. There is nothing in the documentation about `()`, nor about select. This works for me `ogrinfo -sql "GetLayerMetadata counties" TemplateData.gdb`. Usage example can be found from the GDAL autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_openfilegdb.py.

Comment: That works, removing the SELECT statement is key.  Not sure why they call it SQL. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll mark as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Not all SQL begins with `SELECT`. Think about `CREATE TABLE` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the original command.

1. The ogr2ogr utility converts vector data from source format into target format. It is possible to use ogr2ogr but then both datasource and target must be defined. However, ogrinfo might be better tool for making the metadata query.
2. The syntax of the two "SQL requests" which are special for the OpenFileGDB driver must be read literally https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html#special-sql-requests. The documentation should probably call those as "SQL statements" to make it more clear that they are used as they stand, not together with the SELECT statement like many functions. In the syntax of the statements the layer name is separated from the SQL statement by a space, not enclosed between brackets.

> **Special SQL requests**
>
> “**GetLayerDefinition a_layer_name**” and “**GetLayerMetadata a_layer_name**”
> can be used as special SQL requests to get respectively the definition
> and metadata of a FileGDB table as XML content (only available in
> Geodatabases created with ArcGIS 10 or above)

A correct syntax for ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo -sql "GetLayerMetadata counties" TemplateData.gdb
```

A correct syntax for ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f gml -sql "GetLayerMetadata counties" metadata.gml TemplateData.gdb
```